# How can I access a shared folder from R on Ubuntu to a 2nd Ubuntu machine using Samba?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, samba

I have two machines running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Samba installed. I have access to myshared folder as expected.

However, when setting in R the path `smb://mymachine1/mysharedfolder` to read a file it does't find the directory.

I'm new to Ubuntu so I'm sorry if my question results obvious to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL syntax (`smb://…`) is only available in applications using the Gnome libraries. That's mostly GUI applications.

In order to make a Samba mount accessible to all applications, you need to [mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28computing%29) it.

[GVFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS), the system that Gnome uses to access resources such as remote files and archives, can make its own Gnome-only mounts available to all applications in the `~/.gvfs` directory. The path to your file is something like

```
~/.gvfs/mysharedfolder on mymachine1/
```

You can mount GVFS resources on the command line with [`gvfs-mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/en/man1/gvfs-mount.1.html).

#### Checking what's mounted

You can check the status of what's mounting using `gvfs-mount`'s `-l` switch.

```
$ gvfs-mount -l
Drive(0): CD/DVD Drive
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorGdu)
Drive(1): 500 GB Hard Disk
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorGdu)
  Volume(0): SYSTEM_DRV
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorGdu)
  Volume(1): Windows7_OS
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorGdu)
  Volume(2): Lenovo_Recovery
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorGdu)
Mount(0): sam on bart -> smb://BUBBA;sam@bart/sam/
  Type: GDaemonMount
```

In the above output, mounts that are of type: `GDaemonMount` are Samba mounts.

Comment: thanks for your answer. When right-clicking on the folder within network gives the option to unmount. It seems it is already mounted am I wrong?

Comment: @eccehomo - yes if you have to unmount it in the UI then it was mounted.

Comment: @Gilles as I suspected it is already mounted, is the url `smb://user/myfolder/` enough to access from R or in your experience from a plain application? maybe it is just that R doesn't support this feature for linux as I don't have any problem accesssing the same folder from windows.

Comment: @eccehomo Look inside the directory `~/.gvfs` (`ls ~/.gvfs`), you'll see what the mount point is called. Beware that the mount point has spaces in it, you need to quote them in shell scripts.

Comment: @eccehomo Then write `R /home/eccehomo/.gvfs/myfolder\ en\ user/subdirectory/foo.R` instead of `R smb://mymachine1/mysharedfolder/subdirectory/foo.R`

Comment: @Gilles many thanks! I just didn't see how the path to my file looks like in your answer.